# jQuery FancyBox, what is it good for?

Tags: jquery, fancybox

What is the use of a tool such as FancyBox? Any real world examples?

Thanks.

Comment: Well google says

FancyBox is a tool for displaying images, html content and multi-media in a Mac-style "lightbox" that floats overtop of web page

And there are probably about 300,000 real world examples, the site shows you what it can do

Comment: They have a ton of examples on their site under their Tips and Tricks section: http://fancybox.net/blog - we use it a lot for image galleries, modal windows in ajax apps, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scripts like this are a great way to display large images (or other resources, but hearafter referred to as images) on a page without leaving the page or breaking up the layout to accommodate the large image.  They also allow the viewer to easily focus on the large image with reduced distraction from the rest of the page.  Finally, it's quick - no loading new pages, just the image you're viewing.  There are a number of similar scripts based on different JavaScript frameworks and offering different looks and features.

Answer (score 1):

[FancyBox](http://fancybox.net/) has many uses. Personally I use its iFrame display quite alot. But in reality it is probably most used for displaying a large version of an image, so you can display a small thumbnail of an image to users, keeping the page looking neat, while still allowing the user to see the full picture without them being navigated away from the page.

*I have a blog post which shows a real world use of the iFrame function of fancybox, [adding fancybox to blogger.com](http://scoobler.blogspot.com/2011/03/adding-fancybox-to-bloggercom.html)*